a list of N subsequent elements in KDB
Given the table t: ([] a: 1 2 3 4), how can one obtain the column b for e.g.,
n=2
a b
-----
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 ,4

n=3
a b
-------
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 4
3 3 4
4 ,4

where n is the number of subsequent elements of a (including a) to be included in b.

Use next and scan. The left argument is the number of subsequent elements you want:
q)update b:flip 1 next\a from t
a b
----
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4
q)update b:flip 2 next\a from t
a b
------
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 4
3 3 4
4 4


I came up with something that works,
t: ([] a: 1 2 3 4)
n: 3;
f:{[a;n]
    {((count x) & n)#x} each -1_(enlist ,/[a]),({[a;x] a except x }[a] each ,\[a])
 };
show t: update b:f[a;n] from t;

which outputs
a b    
-------
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 4
3 3 4  
4 ,4 

as expected, but I'm concerned that it's not the most efficient nor the most intuitive approach especially for large tables.
